# How to obtain all versions of KRE?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

### Problem

I want to both use stable versions of KRE and the bleeding edge nightly built KRE. One ASP.NET5 application may be beta2, but another I may want to be beta4. So what I did was install both in powershell as found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/home/tree/dev).

What happened is that the stable KVM installed in `C:/Users/derp/.kre` and the nightly build KVM installed in `C:/Users/derp/.k`

Worse yet, I can only see this now
[image]

### Attempts

- I tried `kvm install KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta2` and it failed
- Shall I try moving the packages from `/kre` file to the `/.k` file? This seems hacky and like a really bad idea
- RTFM - Tried to use the install feature and including the `-a`, but failed.
- I'm doing something the hard way and can't see the obvious.
- I search on here

I feel if there is an answer to what I am trying to do above, it is worth being on here for others to find as well. Thank you all for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 is under development and there is no guarantee that changes between different pre-release version are backward compatible (sorry!).

The `/.kre` -> `./k` rename is not backward compatible and you cannot have both the old and the new `kvm` simultaneously on the `PATH`. However, you can get can have two versions of `kvm` on your machine but you will have to use the full path for at least one of them.

Comment: Is it just the nightly build KRE that is .k? Basically, all I want to be able to do is beta2 and beta4 in the same path. If I must, I can try to do this manually, but didn't know if there was a way to "download" beta2 from a remote source.

Comment: @Victor which environment variable VS CTP uses for kre folder? I have found 2 of them which are linked to .k folder but VS still uses .kre folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is the path environment variable of your system. You have to use two set of "kvm", one for night builds, one for public beta, to download and set correct path environment variable.

For instance, I get one kvm from Entity Framework 7 repository, which can download and use beta 4 builds. I also have another kvm from Home repository which can download and use public beta builds.

You can use either kvm with "upgrade" or "use" command to set correct path environment variable, then run your application on the runtime you need. I think even Visual Studio 2015 CTP runs your projects based on the Runtime specified in your path environment variable. For the time being, only beta 3 run times can display in the project property dialog of VS 2015 CTP, but when hitting ctrl + F5, my website starts to load beta 4 runtime and assemblies, I can see the loading in output window, I think this is because I have .k folder prior to the .kre folder in the path environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mentioned two set of "kvm". How do you select which beta you need just using kvm upgrade? Wouldn't you need to alias beta3 and beta4? Last I checked, they both go in the /.k path now (release and nightly)?

Comment: I have 2 kvm folders, when I need to use one of them, I just open a command window, `cd` to the kvm folder I need, then run kvm commands in the current folder. if beta3 and beta4 are in the same .k path, you may use `kvm use` command to choose one of them, then the one you choose will be added to the path variable and start to take effect. For example, `kvm use 1.0.0-beta4-11008 -p`

Comment: you may check which runtime is using by checking the path variable. open a command window and run `echo %path%`, see if the path of the runtime you need exists and is in front of other runtime if any. Sometimes, you also need to logout then login windows to make the path work if you run `kvm use -p` but the path variable doesn't change in new opened command window.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

$cmd-prompt>kpm Install KRE-CLR-x86

It worked for me.